# Integration of frontend(AngularJs) and backend(NodeJS) error

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, angular-resource

Angular code when run on json-server works fine, that is, the data from dishes array of db.json gets served. However, after integration with NodeJS, the data isn't getting served(from MongoDB to frontend). I am pretty sure that both the codes are correct and compatible with each other, as the same code used to work fine on my previous machine. Now, abruptly, even the code on that machine shows the same problem. On the machine on which the code was working, I had disconnected the MongoDB database, without stopping the express server code, whence the things got how they are now.

The integration problem is consistent on my other machine as well, on which I found out about the problem.

While checking the code on browser's console, "ng-src"(and probably other functionalities too) wasn't visible, if that gives a hint.

Following is my code:-
View(AngularJS):-

```
<div ng-controller="HomeController">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-3">
        <div class="media">
                <div class="media-top media-middle">
                    <a ui-sref="#">
                        <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src="{{dish.image}}" alt="MENU" >
                    </a>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading" style="color:red">This is Hot/Featured</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller(AngularJS):-

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {
    menuFactory.getDishes().query(
        function(response) {
            var dishes = response;
            $scope.dish= dishes[0];
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message='Error' + response.status+ " " + response.statusText; 
        });
}])
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {
    menuFactory.getDishes().query(
        function(response) {
            var dishes = response;
            $scope.dish= dishes[0];
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message='Error' + response.status+ " " + response.statusText; 
        });
}])
```

Service(AngularJS):-

```
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {
    menuFactory.getDishes().query(
        function(response) {
            var dishes = response;
            $scope.dish= dishes[0];
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message='Error' + response.status+ " " + response.statusText; 
        });
}])
.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'menuFactory', function($scope, menuFactory) {
    menuFactory.getDishes().query(
        function(response) {
            var dishes = response;
            $scope.dish= dishes[0];
        },
        function(response) {
            $scope.message='Error' + response.status+ " " + response.statusText; 
        });
}])
```

Somebody please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Your controller and your services are identical ? problem with you copy/paste ?

Comment: @Mech45: Sorry that was the problem with copy paste. Anyway thank you for the reply. And sorry for responding so late. The problem was solved.